# Trace of multiplication operator on $L^2(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, trace

Let $H=L^2(\mathbb{T})$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the Torus. Consider a multiplication operator with a sufficiently nice function $f$.

Is there somehow a formula like $$\mathrm{tr} M_f = C \int_{\mathbb{T}} f(x) dx\;\;\;\;\text{ or   }\;\;\;\; \mathrm{tr}|M_f| = C \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{T})}?$$

Or is there another way to compute the trace of a multiplication operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $\mathbb T = S^1 \times S^1$. The case on $\mathbb T$ and $S^1$ is not much different:

There is a standard ONB on $S^1$, namely $e^{i kx}$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$. The point is that that $\langle e^{ikx}| M_f e^{ikx}\rangle =\frac1V\int f$, and if you would sum over all $k$ this diverges unless $\int f =0$, and you have that $M$ is not trace-class.

On the other hand if $\int f = 0$ then you have to note that $M$ is trace class iff $$\sum_i \frac1V \int \overline{e_i}\ |M_f|(e_i) \tag{1}$$ converges for any ONB $e_i$. Now $|M|$ is the unique positive root of $M^*M^\mathstrut$. In this case you can see that $|M_f|=M_{|f|}$. But the result for the basis chosen before shows that the sum (1) diverges unless $\int |f| =0$, that is $f=0$ almost everywhere and $M_f=0$.

This was for $S^1$, but note that $e^{ik x_1}$ are orthonormal on $\mathbb T$ (after rescaling the scalar product maybe), and after extending to an ONB the only way to get that $M_f$ is trace class is once again if $M_f=0$.

Comment: Does such a formula exist for $\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: What kind of a formula do you mean? The formula for the trace of multiplication with a sequence? In that case yes, the operator $M_x$ is trace class iff $x \in \mathscr l^1$ and $Tr(M_x)=\sum_n x_n$.

Comment: Oh yes, that is obvious. Thanks.